# Regex: Extract text between non-unique text string and unique text string

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use regex to extract between a non-unique text string and unique text string over multiple lines and characters

**Example Text:**

```
Blah 
Date: 2nd May 2015
Blah
Unique Report 1
Blah
Date: 1st April 2014
Blah
Blah
Unique Report 2
Blah
```

I am trying to get the date "1st April" which is for the Unique report 2

I am trying the code:

```
(?<= Date:)([\d\D]+?)(Unique Report 2)
```

but this is extracting all the way from the first instance of Date:

Is there a way to go Unique Report 2 and find the 1st instance preceding that of Date:

Thanks

Comment: What are the leading and trailing report boundaries?

Comment: Try [`\bDate: (.*)(?=(?:(?!Unique Report \d+)[\s\S])*Unique Report 2\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/rZ9vV1/1)

Comment: I used  ([\d\D]+?)  as the amount of text between "Unique Report 2" and "Date:"  is variable and over multiple lines

Comment: So, the text you need appears between `Date:` and `Unique Report 2` as a whole word, right?

Comment: Unfortunate not, this would be searching through some XML code for the relevant date and I would just trim the returning string to extract the date

Comment: Then **stop parsing XML with regex**. Use the appropriate tool for that, and you will find it is much easier that you have thought. You won't even need a regex to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work, it is not very generic though:

```
Date\:(\w|[[:space:]])+(?=Blah\sBlah\sUnique Report 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?<=Date: )(?!.*Date:)([^\n]+).*(Unique Report 2)
```

Comment: That only works with DOTALL mode, but looks creepy with unanchored lookarounds.